# Spinner for grid Update

Tags: css, vaadin

We have a Vaadin Grid which has a settings icon. This icon will open a window which allows the user to select/deselect columns. Based on this selection, when the user closes the Vaadin window( we have my own window event), the columns of the main window are updated.
Now, my need is that I need to show a spinner in the center while the main window gets updated( note that this is done after the settings window is closed).

I have not found a spinner which I can show to the user for this kind of scenario. Is there any sample code/scenario which we can use to get this behaviour in Vaadin (without touching the CSS theme files).
If not, is there a way to get this done using CSS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try to use [LazyLoadWrapper add on](http://vaadin.com/addon/lazyloadwrapper)

Also read the discussion about [How to show a loading indicator while rendering complex content on client](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/256316)

With css you can show some loading indicator but I am not sure that is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that.